# How to hide native datepicker in mozilla firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, datepicker

In mozilla firefox showing double date pickers, how do hide native datepicker of mozilla firefox.

I have tried following code:

```
 @inputDate(
     userForm("office.joining_date"),
     'id->"joining_date",
     'name->"joining_date",
     'class->"span4 datepicker",
     '_label->"Joining Date (dd-mm-yyyy)",
     'placeholder ->"Enter Joining Date (dd-mm-yyyy)")
```

Answer (score 1):

> Code is worked after changing inputDate to inputText

```
@inputText(
 userForm("office.joining_date"),
 'id->"joining_date",
 'name->"joining_date",
 'class->"span4 datepicker",
 '_label->"Joining Date (dd-mm-yyyy)",
 'placeholder ->"Enter Joining Date (dd-mm-yyyy)")
```

Answer (score -2):

Need to do some javadcript for native date picker.

```
var nativePicker = document.querySelector('.nativeDatePicker');
nativePicker.style.display = 'none';
```

for more [details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date).
If you created input type date with any js library, You have to change it to input type text.

Comment: What is nativeDatePicker, is it class ? if I add it as a class then hiding whole input box.

Comment: This is a class with appear on the *nativeDatePicker*, not for input box.

Comment: It's not working.. should it needs to import anything?

Comment: How you create datapicker? using jQuery or any other js? How you create input type? Please suggest

Comment: If you created input type date  with any js library, You have to change it to input type text.

Comment: Thanks.. It is worked after modifying it to text. Can you update the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162599/discussion-between-chandraveer-and-ankita-lembhe).